# Coldfusion to PHP

Tags: php, coldfusion

I'm converting an entire site from Coldfusion to PHP.  So, expect many question like this.  How to write this in PHP:

```
<cfif cgi.script_name contains "newsletter">
```

Comment: convert? sounds more like rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second value added to stripos looks like this:

```
    if(stripos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], substr('newsletter', 0))) {

    // do something

    }
```

Comment: substr('newsletter', 0) == 'newsletter' and you should add the "> 0" as a good programming habit as it's far clearer (despite php doing internally the same). Lastly it's bad habit to repost an already given answer and accept your own answer.

Comment: David - your suggested code "> 0" didn't work after many tries.  The code I used for my answer returned the results I needed and is compliant with what I've seen on php.net

Comment: The > 0 part can hardly be the problem, if you run the following code for example:

`$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`
`$page = "/dir/newsletter.php";`
`$posOfStrInPage = stripos($page,"newsletter");`
`if($posOfStrInPage > 0){`
` echo "Newsletter found in current page name on position $posOfStrInPage.<br />";`
`}`
`if(substr('newsletter', 0) === 'newsletter'){`
` echo "Substr from point 0 has no meaning whatsoever, as it's the exact same!";`
`}`

Answer (score 7):

```
if(stripos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],"newsletter") > 0){
```

should do the exact same. Stripos rather than strpos because coldfusion is case insensitive and a simple compare like ceejayoz would be invalid as that would of course only match a specific file (which however might be desirable in a lot of situations, but isn't the same as your cfml).

Answer (score 1):

The closest equivalent will be something like:

```
if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/newsletter.php') {
  // do something
}
```

There's not always going to be a one-to-one function equivalency between CF and PHP, and more context than you've provided is often going to be important as a result.

Comment: I'm on a template page that's included into many other pages.  Most of the time it will display a horizontal navigation, but if it's included  on the "newsletter" page it will display newsletter links.